# jQuery img.load() resulting in additional load each time

Tags: jquery, image, load

I have a background image that I want to reload whenever an ajax event is fired off.  After the background image loads up the new image source, I fade in some other hidden elements.

The problem is that with each ajax load, the background image .load() success function fires off an additional time (first time, 1 load; second time, 2 loads; etc)

[edited to show more context]

```
// all elements that will be updated (fades array) are faded out

// initial ajax request which includes bg image path, new content, etc
$.get( imgSrc, function(data) {

    // set background image src to preloaded image
    $("#content>img").attr({"src": imgData.src});
    $("#content>img").attr({"alt": imgData.alt});
    $("#content>img").attr({"title": imgData.title});

    // update other elements with ajax data
    [...]

    // load image and fade in all other elements
    console.log( 'begin bg image load');
    $("#content>img").load(function() {
       console.log( 'this selector matches ' + $(this).length + ' element');
       console.log( '> begin fades..');
       for(var i=0; i < fades.length; i++){
          $( fades[i] ).fadeTo(750, 1);
       }
       console.log( '> faded in ' + i + ' elements');
    });
});
```

When I initiate the ajax load the third time, the firebug console shows this:

```
begin bg image load
this selector matches 1 element
> begin fades..
> faded in 7 elements
this selector matches 1 element
> begin fades..
> faded in 7 elements
this selector matches 1 element
> begin fades..
> faded in 7 elements
```

My assumptions:

- This is not part of a larger loop: "begin bg image load" is only printed once.
- There is only one #content>img element, although this behavior would make sense if that was not the case.

Does this have something to do with the way .load() operates specifically on images?  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you need to show us how the AJAX stuff is happening too.

Comment: I am setting the src for the image in question earlier using the img path returned from a prior ajax request. I'm assuming that img.load() then loads the updated src, but I guess that's an iffy assumption..

Comment: no, `img.load` _registers_ a callback handler.  Just setting `.src` is sufficient to trigger the reload.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image loading is actually triggered as soon as you set the `src` attribute on the element.

When you call `.load()` you're actually *registering* a new event handler, so each time you call `$.get()` you're re-registrering the handler, *over, and over, and over*.

Comment: Ok, so even though there is only one image being processed one time, it is the multiple event handlers that are producing the issue.  Cool. But that rolls me back to another problem that I thought I had fixed: how do I delay an action (fading in other elements) until after the image has loaded in the browser?

Comment: it might "just work" if you move the whole `.load()` block outside of the `$.get()` callback.

Comment: No good: elements fade in before the image src is set.  According to the firebug console anyway.

Comment: @doub1ejack you're still doing the fades inside the `.load()` callback?

Comment: I commented out the entire `$("#content>img").load()` function and moved the fades loop to the line after `$.get()` ends.

Comment: @doub1ejack You still need _one_ `.load()` function declared _outside_ of the `$.get()` block. The fades should be inside that.

Comment: And moving the whole `$("#content>img").load()` outside the `$.get()` has the same problem as the OP.  Which makes sense because this is inside a routine called at each ajax load. I can't move this `.load()` outside the method because it needs access to the fades array..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13947/discussion-between-doub1ejack-and-alnitak)